# How to Whitelist cloudflare IPs in aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ip-address, cloudflare, aws-security-group

I have my website currently running on aws elastic beanstalk and I am using cloudflare CDN to route traffic.

Everything was working fine for about two weeks now until yesterday when my website starting show the error " connection timed out".

If I come back after a few minutes, everything will go back to normal.

After reading through some community posts on cloudflare, I'm thinking the issue maybe that my security groups is blocking some IP addresses from cloudflare.

So I want to ask where should I add the inbound rules for cloudflare IPs, is it on the security group which my load balancer belongs to or the one that my instances belongs to ?

Comment: It would be the security group assigned to your load balancer, unless you've incorrectly setup Cloufflare to point directly to the EC2 instance somehow. Have you already added some of the Cloudflare IPs to that security group? If not, I really doubt that's the issue.

Comment: Yes, I have added the IPs. But after sometime it still gives the same error.

Comment: How about showing what you have done so far? Did you whitelist all the IPs here (both IPv4 and IPv6)? https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/ Have you tried setting up Cloudflare health checks so you can monitor Cloudflare's connectivity to your servers? https://blog.cloudflare.com/health-check-analytics-and-how-you-can-use-it/ Do you have tiered caching enabled?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that the SG rules that matter are the ones on the load-balancer.
Note: the exception is if you are using a NLB instead of an ALB or classic ELB.
NLBs don't have SGs and you enforce traffic directly on the back-end/EC2 in that case.

If the list of Cloudflare IPs are not 100% static you may want to consider using prefix-lists in your SG rules. Create a prefix-list for Cloudflare IPs and reference that in all your SGs that are depending on openings towards Cloudflare. That way you never have to update a bunch of SGs if the IPs change, you just update the Cloudflare prefix-list in once place, and it takes effect everywhere immediately.

To verify that your SG really is the problem you may want to look into your VPC flowlogs and check if you have a lot of flows in state REJECT, that originate from Cloudflare IPs. If you check the flowlogs for the period when you are experiencing the problem you should see one of two cases, a) you have a lot of REJECT from Cloudflare IPs, or b) you don't have excessive REJECT from Cloudflare IPs.
If it is a) your SG is most likely to blame. If it is b) the traffic never makes it to AWS and your problem is external to AWS and you have to continue your troubleshooting.

CloudWatch Logs Insights may help you query and analyze your flowlogs in a meaningful way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have already removed cloudflare as the CDN due to the above issues. I'm thinking of going with aws cloudfront instead since it integrates well with it's aws origins.

Comment: Any idea on how to set Cloudfront with Elastic beanstalk and aws S3?

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't tried that particular combination myself (CloudFront + Beanstalk), but there are certainly more people out there who have tried.
See for example [this guide](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-connect-your-backend-api-elastic-beanstalk-cloudfront-kamau) for a pretty detailed guide.

Comment: I have decided to finally going with cloudflare CDN instead of aws Cloudfront.

Comment: Currently the security groups of the elastic load balancer is configured to receive both http and https from all ip4 and ip6 sources. That's the source IP addresses are 0.0.0.0/0 and ::/0 but still my website still shows me host error sometimes.